Does hylomorphism have anything to do with the extremely broad use of "form" in scholasticism?
Introductions to the Aristotelian concept of form always begin with hylomorphism: everyday objects (like horses) are composed of matter and form. The form is the intelligibility of the thing (e.g., horse-ness), whereas the matter is the individuality of the thing (that horse).
But one frequently finds scholastic philosophers speaking of the form of abstract objects, as when Aquinas says that "charity is the form of virtues." Whatever "form" means here, but it seems different from "form" as defined in hylomorphism. So the original, hylomorphic definition of form seems to be much too narrow. What am I missing here?

While the term "form" originates from Aristotle's hylomorphic framework refers to the essential nature or formal cause that defines a particular substance or kind of thing as secondary substance in a purely metaphysical sense, its usage in medieval scholastic philosophy expands to encompass not only substantial forms but also the essences or defining characteristics of abstract entities together with the metaphysical accidental forms that specify accidental properties of substances, such as color, shape, and size...
